# SDL Tridion "demo" account?

Tags: core-service, cme, content-manager

I met various people who would like to see the interface, some basic things, component creation, etc. to see how it looks like in real world.
I can't show the instance I'm maintaining as it's internal in my company, but is there somewhere some kind of "demo" available with ability to login to see a real Tridion interface and it's basic services, coreservices to connect to via API? To see creation of content components, etc. Or there is no such option?
I know that these Tridion instances are quite specific to the needs of the actual customer, so they are all different, but I met different products already with such an online trial/demo account earlier.
I assume the answere will be NO...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is correct as the Answer is NO.

You may want to refer the similar question I have asked few months ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003091/sdl-tridion-license

Comment: I've flagged the question for moderator attention. Hoping we can get the SO question moved here.

Comment: @Pankaj Gaur ,Thanks! Good question/post, would be really nice to move that here Dominic!

Comment: Since it is not viable to move every [`tridion`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tridion) tagged question from SO to here, we sort of decided to only move the new questions from now on. So I propose we'll do the same here and let this one exists and accept it as a duplicate from SO.

Answer (score 7):

There are training amazon instances but they are not free, if you are interested you should contact the sales department.

Comment: Thanks, will try to contact them, seems for now the only option to become a partner or to buy a Tridion instance. :) I don't know, which one is cheaper?

Comment: @BVL the sales department will be able to tell you which is cheaper in your case, there are different benefits with each.

Comment: @BVL The partner should be cheaper one, but just paying the fees will not make you eligible for the partner - you should also be in line of SDL's vision and there are other criteria for the same

Answer (score 4):

Don't rule out reaching out to [SDL education](http://www.sdl.com/services/education-certification/training-product/web-content-management/) for access to either the training environment (not typical) or to maybe purchase eLearning.

To get a basic feel of Tridion, you can find images, blog posts, and some videos online.  I have [some short examples on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP2_nODxwPo&list=PL0E10CC8C16CC4EEA) and am overdue for adding more. [Kah Tang](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/57/kah-tang) has a more [in-depth example of 2011](http://youtu.be/kD3IAmyZwqQ).

[Joining someone (SDL, a partner, or customer), getting trained, and/or sharing Tridion knowledge](http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/11/how-to-get-to-play-with-sdl-tridion.html) are currently the best ways to get access to an SDL Tridion environment.