# How do I get GA License for Tridion 2011 to Setup VM for Local Usage

Tags: 2011, licensing

As Per the article in SDLTridionWorld.com How would I get the GA License for Tridion 2011 to setup VM installation Local Usage.

Creating a Development VM - Part 1: Setting up the VM
This document details the steps required to install and test the SDL Tridion Content Manager 2011 server on a Windows 2008 R2 platform, with a SQL Server backend.

http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/creating-development-vm-1.aspx

Comment: You may like to refer these posts/questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003091/sdl-tridion-license

http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/sdl-tridion-demo-account/2959#2959

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite for that link is, you should have license. License is not availble for trial/free use. You have to contact the sales people

More details on following link:

[does-sdl-offer-a-free-developer-download](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/855/does-sdl-offer-a-free-developer-download/856#856)